# Magento 1.9.4.0 order not creating

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, orders, session

I have been working on integration of a payment gateway with Magento 1.9.4.0 it works perfectly and the orders are being created successfully. However, there is a case when the user tries to login before the checkout step, the order is not being created. I digged down the issue and found that the code stops on the following line:

```
public function successAction()
{
    $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
    if (!$session->getLastSuccessQuoteId()) {
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
        return;
    } ....
```

After googling i came to know that this issue has been fixed by Magento in the SUPEE 9767 V2 Patch. I checked for that to apply on my site but that is not available for M1.9.4.0 Version. I tried multiple solutions but in vain.The values are not present in the session on which magento decides to create the order and redirect the user to the success page. Can someone recommend best possible solution to the issue?

Comment: i was able to resolve the issue myself. Issue was with the plugin we were using. For logged in users it created the first order but for next orders within the same session, it was not creating orders. Issue was with the Reserved Order ID that magento assigns just before creating the order. the plugin was saving the value in the session and was not unsetting it. i just unset the value before reserving the order id and the issue was fixed.